Android - How can I get Talkback to read out menuItems in BottomNavigationView menu's content descriptions properly?
There are a few results I wanted to achieve but I was unable to achieve any. The goal of my tasks are to have the content description for menu items in a BottomNavigationView be more friendly for talkback. While this can easily be achieved from other solutions I found by setting the contentDescription as follows:
bottomNav.menu.findItem(R.id.item1)?.contentDescription = "description here"

This provides a jarring order of feedback that sounds as follows when read back:
"Content Description. Menu title. Tab. One of Two. Double Tap to Select"
If I were to provide a content description that describes what the tap does, for example navigation to a page, it would sound like: "Navigate to next page. Next. Tab. One of Two. Double Tap to Select." Where Next is the menu title.
This doesn't sound right, but there was another angle I wanted to try, where I could replace the "Select" portion of "Double Tap to Select" with my own AccessibilityDelegate similar to buttons, which I won't go into here as I follow other workable solutions already for buttons. But for menuItems with BottomNavigationView, I cannot get it to work, "Select" will always be read out no matter how I try to write my custom AccessibilityDelegate.
I have tried an answer like this one, but even after following it, it doesn't work for me because it does nothing.
Overall, both avenues I desire to achieve I cannot, and I'm stuck with a terrible feedback from Talkback that describes the action before reading out the tab title and being unable to overwrite the "Select" text like I can with custom AccessbilityDelegates on buttons.
Any tips or links would be appreciated.
Just in case: here is my XML and Kotlin code:
bottomnavigationmenu.xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:title="@string/item1"
        android:icon="@drawable/item1icon"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:title="@string/item2"
        android:icon="@drawable/item2icon"/>
</menu>

bottomnavigationview element inside a constraintlayout
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_colorstatelist"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_colorstatelist"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavButton"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottomnavigationmenu" />

setting bottomnavigation to my navigation graph
 val bottomNav = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation).apply {
            setupWithNavController(navController)
        }

